# Why is the second one wrong?

Tags: sentence

1. We need to be serious (if we want) to succeed in the examination.
2. We will be serious to be successful in the examination.

The second one is wrong. Please tell me why.

Comment: I don't think #2 is "wrong" in any syntactic or grammatical sense. It's just idiomatically unlikely, though it becomes more credible if you introduce a comma/pause and/or explicitly include something like ***in order*** after ***serious***, to emphasize the "purposeful" aspect of the statement (which more naturally attaches to ***need*** than to ***will be***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not clear about what the sentence is saying. Is seriousness a prerequisite or not? Or is it that the two go hand in hand? On what basis are they correlated? The sentence leaves me uncertain as to what its author is thinking. On that basis it is surely ungrammatical, isn't it? .

Comment: _We must be serious to be successful in the examination._ works for me

Comment: @WS2: I think you'd have your work cut out trying to define a rule allowing [*...the opening convention session **will be brief to allow** maximum attendance at the machinery exhibitions*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22session+will+be+brief+to%22), but debarring OP's syntactically-equivalent version. (I assume you don't reject my example as "ungrammatical"! :)

Comment: Perhaps the examination is testing your ability to keep a straight face. In that case, you might confirm with your classmates the best approach: "We will be serious *[so as]* to be successful..."  It sounds grammatical to me. But really, it's a very unlikely turn of phrase.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your intention is to highlight a prerequisite to a goal.
In your first sentence, the goal is to succeed in the examination. The required step to reach the goal is the need to be serious. The sentence correctly observe the causality effect. [More about necessity and sufficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency)

The second sentence is not entirely wrong, but the meaning is slightly different as it does not strongly address causality as the first one does.

Comment: Whilst I agree in principle, the second sentence is not exactly grammatical. To imply causality it would have to say *We have to be serious to be successful in an examination*. As it stands I am not absolutely clear what it is saying. Could it be *Success and seriousness go hand in hand* - or what?

Answer (score 0):

The use of future tense (i.e., *will be*) does not confirm the prediction of *to be successful.* Use of the Future Perfect (i.e. *will have been*) relates to something that will already have happened before a certain time in the future.